# Should I use Nutch 1x or 2x with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nutch

I've been using Nutch 1.10 to index data into Elasticsearch for a couple of years. Awhile ago, I decided to start the upgrade process to newer versions of both Nutch and ES.

After lots of Googling, it seems people are using Nutch 2.x more and more even though it seems that Nutch 1.x is faster and under more active development. It also seems that after Nutch 1.10, it has become more difficult to use Nutch 1x with ES.

It seems the BIG difference is that you can store the crawled data into different databases with Nutch 2.x. It seems that Nutch 1.x is really good at crawling and crawling fast but thats it.

So which version of Nutch is best to use with ES v2+ or ES v5x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running Nutch for production it's probably better to stick to Nutch 1.x, it has more features and as you said performs better than 2.x. As for the ES compatibility, I don't think there is a lot of difference.

Nutch 1.x actually is shipped with compatibility with ES 5.3, this means that if you download the `.zip` file (or build directly from the source) then you'll get the ES client libraries for v5.3.

There is a bit of documentation explaining how to upgrade https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/plugin/indexer-elastic/howto_upgrade_es.txt. Of course, this "path" for upgrading depends on how well the ES client library doesn't change its public API (which could happen) at which point a PR will be more than welcome.

Nutch 2.x is a little behind (still ships with support to ES 1.x,2.x) but it has a similar upgrade documentation subject to the same warning as before.

Another option is to use the `indexer-elastic-rest` plugin which doesn't rely on the ES client library but on the Jest library from Searchly (https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest) this means that the documents will be sent using the REST API instead of using the binary protocol that ES client library supports.

In any case, Nutch 1.x is more actively maintained and as you can see is more updated than the 2.x branch.

Comment: If I want to use the REST api with Elasticsearch - which version would you recommend. Been doing lots of searches here and on Google and the REST api seems to favor Nutch 2x - and it looks like there is a web app that gives a partial UI?

Answer (score 2):

Go for Nutch 1.X, I am using nutch 1.14 With ES 5.6.0 using **indexer-elastic-rest** and Its Working Seamlessly without any Issue.

Comment: can you give me some pointers on how you got Nutch 1x working using the indexer-elastic-rest plugin. Looking at the docs now but bin/nutch startserver doesn't give me any output in the cli

Comment: You can use **indexer-elastic-rest** plugin, I am attaching the link to my property file: [link to nuth-site.xml](https://github.com/iamhigh/nutch-plugins/blob/master/conf/nutch-site.xml) use these properties to get it working.

Comment: thank you! No wander I'm having such trouble, I must have 15 properties set in my nutch-site.xml

Comment: well kind of. I no longer get an error about indexing - it says the content was indexed but then I go to check the index via Kibana and use the _stats to check the document count and it says 0. Not sure what I'm doing wrong still

Comment: Make sure that you are checking the same index the you mentioned in nutch-site.xml

Comment: I looked at your repo and saw the crawl commands file. So your using the crawl commands and NOT the Nutch 1x REST API? Also did you have to update the Jest REST api with Nutch or did you just use the default 2x version that comes with it?

Comment: Yes I was using the crawl commands and I didnt do anything with the jest rest api.

Comment: I'm using ES 5.3 - in nutch-default.xml - under <plugin.includes> has no mention of indexer-elastic-rest - how did you include it?  I obviously don't want to use Solr